# kafka fetch request cannot fetch any messages if there is a single message that is bigger than fetch size

Tags: apache-kafka

In the kafka manual website, there is this code block that fetch messages from kafka. but it doesn't work if there is a single message bigger than fetch size.

However, we don't know in advance what will be the maximum size coming to the queue. Is there any way to make it always fetch at least one message?

```
import kafka.api.FetchRequest;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer;
import kafka.javaapi.message.ByteBufferMessageSet;
import kafka.message.Message;
import kafka.message.MessageSet;
import kafka.utils.Utils;

...

// create a consumer to connect to the kafka server running on localhost, port 9092, socket timeout of 10 secs, socket receive buffer of ~1MB
SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer("127.0.0.1", 9092, 10000, 1024000);

long offset = 0;
while (true) {
  // create a fetch request for topic “test”, partition 0, current offset, and fetch size of 1MB
  FetchRequest fetchRequest = new FetchRequest("test", 0, offset, 1000000);

  // get the message set from the consumer and print them out
  ByteBufferMessageSet messages = consumer.fetch(fetchRequest);
  for(MessageAndOffset msg : messages) {
    System.out.println("consumed: " + Utils.toString(msg.message.payload(), "UTF-8"));
    // advance the offset after consuming each message
    offset = msg.offset;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches here: configure your server to reject messages larger than the max message size your consumers can fetch. Make sure your broker's max.message.bytes setting and your consumer's fetch.message.max.bytes are the same before producing / consuming on a topic (see https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html). This will push the problem to producers to figure out how to keep message sizes from being too large.

The alternate approach is to increase the fetch-max-bytes on your consumer and retry. So catch MessageSizeTooLarge error from consumer.fetch(fetchRequest) and retry this w/ a larger max message size (the last parameter, 1000000 in your example code):

`FetchRequest fetchRequest = new FetchRequest("test", 0, offset, 1000000)`

But this is dangerous -- which is the point of the max message size configuration.

I recommend pushing the message size constraints to your producers.